# Which Python to use on Windows for Numpy and friends?

Tags: python, windows, module, installation, numpy

For research related Python programs, I require Python 2.6 (or 2.7), numpy, scipy and matplotlib. Occasionally, I'm going to use other modules such as [mayavi2](http://mayavi.sourceforge.net/) or [numexpr](http://code.google.com/p/numexpr/).

The programs in questions will be exchanged between (Ubuntu) Linux and Windows and can be modified to work across platforms. The setup on the Windows side should resemble the Linux one as closely as possible. Integration with COM, .NET, or the Windows OS is not required.

I'm aware of the following options:

- [Python for Windows](http://python.org/download/) from python.org
- [ActivePython](http://www.activestate.com/activepython)
- [Python(x,y)](http://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/), a bundle of Python with modules and GUIs
- [Enthought Python distribution](http://www.enthought.com/products/epd.php), a bundle of Python with modules

Which of those will provide me most efficiently with a setup that just works? And how would they differ?

Comment: I use Python for Windows(from your list) and it works fine

Comment: You say win python straight from python.org works fine for you. It sure does with pure Python code but, in my experience, setting it up to compile binary extensions is far from easy. Even if you don't make your own binary extensions, packages such as numpy go through a compilation phase during installation, so you cannot simply "pip install" them. There are binary installers for these sort of packages that you can hunt around for, but then maintaining things up-to-date becomes a chore. ActivePython, PythonXY and EPD offer you all these packages ready to use, and can save MUCH inconvenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is old, but the answer nowadays to this question will always be Anaconda, so I thought I provide you a link to it.

Not only for scientfic purposes - it has all the libraries and tools for this, installed - but its also the best python distribution in general:
https://www.anaconda.com/download/

Comment: Anaconda has also a lot of disadvantages. Primarily the fact that you need to "activate environments" before running executables from its budle – for example pandoc or some python console.

Answer (score 8):

**EDIT 2017-11-4**: At this point in time [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads.html) seems by far to be the best option. It is multi-platform, doesn't require admin/root permission, and it allows you to install multiple python versions in parallel.

**Original post**

The easiest way to install all the python libraries necessary for scientific computing is to install either Python(x,y) or Enthought Python Distribution (EPD). Both offer a fairly similar set of packages (including numexpr and mayavi2), so it's probably just a matter of personal preference. I prefer Python(x,y) because it is fully open source, whereas EPD is a commercial product with a free edition. You can compare the included packages for [EPD](http://www.enthought.com/products/epdlibraries.php) and [Python(x,y)](http://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/wiki/StandardPlugins).

Both these options are much better than using the standard python (or ActiveState) then manually installing all the required scientific packages. Both should work well with code transported from Linux. It's worth mentioning that EPD also has a Linux version, so if you need all packages and versions to be *absolutely* identical between Windows and Linux setups, this might be the way to go.

Edit:The win32-superpack is a good option if you just want a few basic scientific packages, but if you want more complex things like mayavi, you'd need to install them yourself.

**Edit 2013-05-03:**

There are now a couple of other options which are also worth considering: [winpython](https://code.google.com/p/winpython/) and [anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads.html)

Comment: I was not aware of the free edition of the EPD.  What is the difference to the commercial one?  Anyway, the Python(x,y) distribution looks very interesting.  I will give it a try the next time that I need Python under Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the [win32-superpack](http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/scipy/0.10.0/) from the official SciPy distribution.  It includes Python, NumPy, SciPy, matplotlib, etc. and everything works out of the box.

Maybe I should also comment on the packages on your list:

- The standard Python distribution from Python.org does not include SciPy, as far as I know.
- The Enthought distribution is installed on some of the computer clusters that I am using.  It is linked against the Intel MKL and could be faster for linear algebra than the SciPy one.  But it is a commercial package.  Python programs developed with the SciPy distribution should, however, run without problems under Enthought, too.
- I don't know anything about the other two distributions.